# What does MAKE_LINTIAN_HAPPY and a single quote in a shell script do?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

In a `sh` script I came across, I found the lines

```sh
#\
MAKE_LINTIAN_HAPPY '
```

close to the beginning.

From the name of the identifier, it is clear why it was added. But **my question is: Why is this legal sh code and what (if anything) does it do?**

---

The reason I ask is that it renders [GNU's source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) useless on this script since it will interpret all of the file after the tick as a string. If I know why it's legal, it might be possible to suggest an edit to the language definition file to fix this.

I tried to search the `man` pages for `sh` for clues with

```sh
$ man sh|grep "\W'\W"
```

but none of the matches seem to be of help (there are many matches though so I might have missed it if it's there).

I don't understand the `#\` either; I don't know if this is unrelated to this question or not. (`Vim` will syntax-color the line following `#\` as a comment, but a simple test shows that `sh` does execute the line following `#\`.)

Here's an extended excerpt of the beginning of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# [...]
#\
exec tclsh $0 -- "$@"

#\
MAKE_LINTIAN_HAPPY '

set PROG_VERSION "v1.27 17/06/2005"
```

Comment: "Lintian is a helper tool used in conjunction with dpkg, the Debian package management system." See http://lintian.debian.org/ . Good luck.

Comment: is there a previous `'` ?

Comment: what kind of warnings does lintian produce, if you remove the `MAKE_LINTIAN_HAPPY` line?

Comment: @karoly-horvath: I don't know what warning, I've never used lintian. And no - the ' on the line in question is the first occurance of ' in the file.

Comment: well, if you are interesting, you should check it. and... is there a closing one?

Comment: Do you have the source history of the original file? There should be a note there explaining why this was added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script you are looking at is in fact not a shell (sh, bash, dash, etc) script, but a tclsh script. When you start it, then, in fact, /bin/sh is first started. The very first command it executes is

```
exec tclsh $0 -- "$@"
```

meaning it fires up tclsh and passes the very script file to tclsh. Now tclsh starts to interpret the script. It also has '#' as the start of a line comment, but in contrast to sh, the line comment can be extended to the next line, if the end-of-line is escaped, hence `#\`.

So the `MAKE_LINTIAN_HAPPY` line is not a command for tclsh, it is just ignored. The first command executed by  tclsh is `set PROG_VERSION ...`.

I don't know lintian. This line may have exactly the purpose of letting lintian "misinterpret' the contents of the file as just text, because it would otherwise think it is an sh script and would yell loud about policy violations.

Comment: +1 Good analysis. And the last paragraph seems entirely plausible.